# Start a command based application from the GNOME search box

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell

I just installed Firefox 57 on my Ubuntu 17.10 box. Firefox came as an `tar.bz2` file, so I extracted it and are able to start Firefox by issuing this command: `/path/to/firefox`.

Is it possible to start Firefox from the GNOME search box, as I could when I installed older Firefox instances by the use of `.deb` files?

Comment: Firefox 57 has been released and the Firefox 57 update can be installed using the Software Updater application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a `.desktop` file for Firefox 57 (say `firefox57.desktop`) in `~/.local/share/applications`. You may use the following format:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Launch Firefox 57
Terminal=false
Name=Firefox 57
Exec=full/path/to/firefox-57
Type=Application
Icon=firefox
```

Now if you search for "Firefox 57" in GNOME search box, it should appear.

**Notes:**

- Provide the `full/path/to/firefox-57` in the `Exec=` line (i.e. put `/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/Downloads/...` instead of `~/Downloads/...`)
- This Firefox 57 launcher will use the Firefox icon specified by your icon theme. You can use a custom icon (preferably a `.png` or `.svg` image) by specifying its full path in the `Icon=` line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just came across https://itsfoss.com/firefox-quantum-ubuntu/, and decided to install Firefox beta using PPA, so I won't need to set up the launcher after all. But thanks for the information anyway, I'm sure it will come in handy later on.